Spark Streaming java.io.InvalidClassException: projectname.clasname; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID
I create a Spark Streaming app with Spark 2.0.2 and Scala 2.11.8. In my app, a class extends Serializable. But when I add new fields to this class, this error is displayed when running on Spark.
Exception in thread "main" java.io.InvalidClassException: projectname.clasname; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -6009442170907349114, local class serialVersionUID = 6529685098267757690
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:562)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1582)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1495)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1731)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)

If I add anotation @SerialVersionUID(-6009442170907349114l), that error disappears but new fields of class are set default null.
How can I add new fields to class which extends Serializable with Scala and Spark Streaming?
